# 'Failed to find font-family tag' when uploading using Chrome browser on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, file-upload

I have an javascript app which uploads photos. Uploading works when developing locally in my Chrome browser. However when I run the app on my android phone (or my android notepad), it ignores the first time I select a photo and ***only works the second time*** I select a photo (could be a different photo second time). This is the case when selecting an existing photo, or when taking a picture (fist time nothing happens, second time uploads as should). I tried to debug this using a usb connection with Chrome remote devices, but then suddenly the 'bug' is gone (photo gets uploaded on first selection).

Another thing I tried: I selected `chrome://user-actions` in another chrome tab. As soon as I do however the bug is gone again, it works as should so I can not debug!

On both Firefox and Safari the upload of photos works as should.

I installed Android Studio and can now connect my phone via usb and get useful logs in the Logcat window of Android Studio. When bug occurs I get following logs that look like the culprit to me:

```
E/ResourcesCompat: Failed to find font-family tag
```

For example a succesful upload:

```
2019-04-20 09:42:44.669 1090-1211/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-04-20 09:43:00.546 1831-1875/? W/libprocessgroup: Failed to open process cgroup uid 99035 pid 17754: No such file or directory
2019-04-20 09:43:00.547 1831-1875/? E/libprocessgroup: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99035 pid 17754: No such file or directory
2019-04-20 09:43:00.587 1831-1878/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq stats for CPUs 4-7
2019-04-20 09:43:00.588 1831-1878/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq stats for CPUs 0-3
2019-04-20 09:43:22.689 905-1110/? W/qti_sensors_hal: processReportInd: lux: 123, ch0: 84, ch1: 151, pData: 24, pOffset: 6
2019-04-20 09:43:23.186 905-1650/? W/qti_sensors_hal: reportSingleEvent: NearBy 1, pData 108, pOffset 6, highThres 97, lowThres 72
2019-04-20 09:43:23.282 905-1650/? W/qti_sensors_hal: reportSingleEvent: NearBy 0, pData 31, pOffset 6, highThres 97, lowThres 72
2019-04-20 09:43:23.672 905-1110/? W/qti_sensors_hal: processReportInd: lux: 142, ch0: 95, ch1: 163, pData: 5, pOffset: 6
2019-04-20 09:43:42.544 18563-18563/? E/contentprovide: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-04-20 09:43:44.671 1090-1211/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-04-20 09:43:46.515 905-1110/? W/qti_sensors_hal: processReportInd: lux: 165, ch0: 108, ch1: 171, pData: 6, pOffset: 6
2019-04-20 09:43:47.506 9494-9494/? E/ResourcesCompat: Failed to find font-family tag
2019-04-20 09:43:47.509 9494-9494/? E/ResourcesCompat: Failed to find font-family tag
```

A Failed upload:

```
2019-04-20 09:45:00.184 1831-1875/? W/libprocessgroup: Failed to open process cgroup uid 99037 pid 19100: No such file or directory
2019-04-20 09:45:00.184 1831-1875/? E/libprocessgroup: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99037 pid 19100: No such file or directory
2019-04-20 09:45:00.216 9494-9494/? E/ResourcesCompat: Failed to find font-family tag
2019-04-20 09:45:00.225 1831-1878/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq stats for CPUs 4-7
2019-04-20 09:45:00.222 9494-9494/? E/ResourcesCompat: Failed to find font-family tag
2019-04-20 09:45:00.227 1831-1878/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq stats for CPUs 0-3
2019-04-20 09:45:00.247 19263-19263/? E/decoder_servic: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-04-20 09:45:00.313 19263-19279/? W/FileUtils: Failed to chmod(/data/user/0/com.android.chrome/app_chrome): android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2019-04-20 09:45:00.314 19263-19279/? E/cr_PathUtils: Failed to set permissions for path "/data/user/0/com.android.chrome/app_chrome"
2019-04-20 09:45:00.314 19263-19279/? W/FileUtils: Failed to chmod(/data/user/0/com.android.chrome/app_textures): android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2019-04-20 09:45:00.314 19263-19279/? W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure /data/user/0/com.android.chrome/cache: mkdir failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2019-04-20 09:45:00.314 19263-19279/? W/ContextImpl: Failed to update user.inode_cache: stat failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2019-04-20 09:45:00.315 19263-19279/? W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure /data/user/0/com.android.chrome/cache: mkdir failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2019-04-20 09:45:00.315 19263-19279/? W/ContextImpl: Failed to update user.inode_cache: stat failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Only pointer I find is that for all failures the `Failed to find font-family tag` comes BEFORE `Failed to read cpu-freq stats`.

Any clues?